# Install UNICASE eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I'm trying to insall UNICASE in Eclipse following this [guide](http://unicase.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/documentation/UNICASE_Manual.pdf). This software requires installing a client (Unicase) and a server (EMFStore server). Unfortunately by using Eclipse 'marketplace' or 'install new software' options (in help menu) I can't get them together. Every time Eclipse asks me to remove the plugin just installed to get the other one (example: when installing EMFStore server after Unicase it ask me to remove Unicase).

Can someone help me to make UNICASE work?

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. I just tried the follow:

1. In Eclipse go to Help-->Eclipse Marketplace
2. Search for UNICASE

A UNICASE market place appeared for UNICASE Client. Proceed with installation.

After Eclipse reboot, a UNICASE perspective is installed (Window-->Open perspective --> Other)